# How to increment a counter value inside a class in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a class in some javascript that is incremented using i each time the code is looped though.
In the code it is referenced as

```
'#line2_attrib_no'+i
```

I now need to add some additional function that requires me to apply the same to a class also marked with the class name adult.
I tried to use

```
$('#line2_attrib_no'+i 'option.adult').toggle(this.value == 2);
```

but this doesn't work. I also tried it as

```
#line2_attrib_no+i option.adult'
```

but this also fails to function.
Is there a specific method to approach this kind of situation? I did have a look on the internet but haven't found anything useful. This may be down to not knowing how to actually describe what it is I want to do.

Comment: Typo. You mean `$('#line2_attrib_no' + i + ' option.adult')` though it looks like you're trying to use the same ID on two elements

Comment: It's used to remove options from a select dropdown that is duplicated multiple times to collect ticket names,depending on the quantity selected by the user. On Child tickets, only Mr or Miss were required in the title dropdown. line2 being the line number of the second attribute, i being the number from the total required.

Comment: Not sure why someone saw fit to mark the question as a -1. It was a genuine question from someone who does not know javascript/jquery and I tried various methods before I decided to ask for help.

Comment: I didn't, but questions whose answers are simple typos can get that.

Comment: Whilst the missing + might appear to be just a typo to someone who understands the code, the importance of the + wasn't known to me. I mistakenly thought it meant increase 'i' by one, not add the value of 'i' to this data string. Hence me not putting an additional + in my attempts to get it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
$('#line2_attrib_no'+ i +' option.adult').toggle(this.value == 2);
```

Comment: That did the trick. So using the + basically just appends whatever follows it to the previous data? In this case i being the incrementing value, and then the second part of the class name i wanted to perform an action on.

Comment: yeah pretty much. In essence, you have concatenated value of "i" into "#line2_attrib_no" and " option.adult".

Comment: Thanks Ash. JQuery always seems like black magic to me. I'm picking it up slowly though.

Comment: The issue wasn't about jQuery, it was not understanding how to concatenate in JS.